# Build a control within a circle/ellipse on Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, ellipse

I want to use a circle/ellipse as a design element around a custom control (three text blocks) on Windows Phone.  I am having trouble finding any examples.  It seems like this should be rather simple.

I want to make the control a little more complex by adding select boxes for two of the text blocks.

Think of it as simply selecting minutes and seconds and then running a timer with a circle around it to differentiate it from other controls on the page.

Comment: So what's not working when using an ellipse in your XAML?

Comment: I got it.  I was using a StackPanel.  I'm still working to understand the design elements.  I should have posted the code.  Thanks for the response.  It actually helped to clarify that it should be possible.